# Java built in monitoring tool

Tags: java, monitoring

Once I have found a "built in" monitoring tool in the java installation folder, bzw. the subfolder lib or bin.

But I can't find it any more, also in the search engine of my choice.

Maybe you know which tool I mean and can help me.

Thank you and kind regards!

Comment: You are looking for jconsole or jmc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about

> Java Mission Control, jvisualvm and JConsole

You can find them in "your jdk/bin", please note i am using jdk 8.

Comment: "Java VisualVM was first bundled with the Java platform, Standard Edition (Java SE) in JDK version 6, update 7." according to [this site](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jvisualvm-What-Is-Java-VisualVM.html)